# WPF ContextMenu swallowing all mouse events

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

I found one bug, and I don't understand, why it's happening.
I have DataGrid. On left mouse button click I want to open ContextMenu.
I made it. It works fine until I start clicking on DataGrid's Cells on random (every time ContextMenu is closing and reappearing at new place). But at one moment something is happening and ContextMenu newer showing (and Window don't response to any Mouse events like clicking on buttons and so on)... until I move cursor out of window and return it (or clicking Alt or F10).

Here some code:
ContextMenu (inside `<DataGrid.Resources>`)

```
<ContextMenu Style="{StaticResource DefaultContextMenuStyle}" x:Key="cm"
     DataContext="{Binding Data, Source={StaticResource WindowViewModel}}">
</ContextMenu>
```

DataGrid column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TestHeader" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel ContextMenu="{StaticResource cm}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:OpenContextMenuLeftBehavior />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextVCenteredCellStyle}" Text="{Binding LPU}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And behavior to open ContextMenu:

```
public class OpenContextMenuLeftBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp += OpenContextMenu;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp -= OpenContextMenu;
    }

    void OpenContextMenu(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) {
            FrameworkElement Sender = sender as FrameworkElement;
            Sender.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = Sender;
            Sender.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I found that bug, I tried to find some info with Snoop WPF.
And here some info from it:

1. Before bad thing happened one click on cell was like:
   [before bad thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv2nZ.png)
2. After bad thing:
   [after bad thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U1QpI.png)
   First event happened at Popup (ContextMenu part?), it doesn't belong to window VisualTree. This Popup seems to stretch all over the main Window and closing, when i move mouse out of it.

So, I lost 2 days on that bug and this is all, that I can find.
Please help me.

**EDIT:
I created minimal example:**

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dg1" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DockPanel>
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <local:OpenContextMenuLeftBehavior />
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu>
                                        <MenuItem Header="123456"></MenuItem>
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                                <TextBlock Text="123" />
                            </DockPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dg1.ItemsSource = new List<int>()
        {
            1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
        };
    }
}

public class OpenContextMenuLeftBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp += OpenContextMenu;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.PreviewMouseUp -= OpenContextMenu;
    }

    void OpenContextMenu(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left) {
            FrameworkElement Sender = sender as FrameworkElement;
            if (Sender != null) {
                Sender.ContextMenu.PlacementTarget = Sender;
                Sender.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
                Sender.ContextMenu.UpdateLayout();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce this bug just click rapidly on different cells

Comment: please post the code for the Style `DefaultContextMenuStyle`

Comment: @Massimiliano Kraus , there is only background color

Comment: Please, create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revised Answer

After you published a full, simple example, I'd suggest the following:
after you create the ContextMenu

```
                    Sender.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
                    Sender.ContextMenu.PreviewMouseUp += ContextMenu_PreviewMouseUp;
```

Having defined

```
    private void ContextMenu_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var Sender = (sender as ContextMenu);
        if (Sender != null)
        {
            Sender.IsOpen = true;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

(you still have to manage the grid line selection, but it's like off topic here)

Comment: No, it doesn't help.

Comment: @FrantsevM Revised. Try also with `UpdateLayout`

Comment: And what *really* doesn't help is that you're not sharing a complete example and a clear, deterministic sequence of steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I added simple example.

Comment: @FrantsevM Thanks, let me have a quick look at it, if I can replicate the issue...

Comment: @FrantsevM ok, I've proposed a workaround, it looks fine, as far as I can see, within the scope of this simple example